# Outside of cycle implies winding number=0?

Tags: complex-analysis

Outside of cycle implies winding number 0?

I think this is trivially true at least intuitively.

But I can not prove this. How can i approach this one?

Comment: The winding number is constant in each component, and it has an integral representation. Send the point you're computing the winding number at to infinity.

Comment: @user AH! I almost forgot that fact! that fact save me! Thanks! BTW, How about the case that domain is bounded?